# Output of the trained neural network for a set of inputs

Tags: fitting, machine-learning, neural-networks

Sorry if this was too trivial but I want to get the output of the neural network I trained for the specific inputs that I feed. The notation I often saw was of TrainedNet[inp] kind. But when I use this I do not get the output but the result given in figure below:[image]

Comment: Can you share the `NetTrain` invocation? I suspect you did `NetTrain[mynet, data, All]` - if you try something like `results["TrainedNet"][inp]` that may work. To avoid this, you can just do `NetTrain[mynet, data]` (ie, no `All`).

Comment: Yes I was using it with All. It works fine when I remove the All. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you used `NetTrain[mynet, data, All]`, which returns a `NetTrainResultsObject`. From a `NetTrainResultsObject`, you can use `["TrainedNet"]` (eg, `results["TrainedNet"]`) to get the network, or you can retrain your network with `NetTrain[mynet, data]` which will only return the trained net.

Further reading: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrainResultsObject.html https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrain.html